# SELECT DISTINCT in mysqli prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to convert a mysql function into mysqli prepared statement.

however, I have problems getting it to work especially the select distinct.

is there any difference between select distinct in mysql function and mysqli prepared statement?

**This works:**

```
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM $storeShop";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());

    // For each result that we got from the Database
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
     $cvalue[] = $line;
    }
    // Assign this array to smarty...

    $smarty->assign('category', $cvalue);
// Assign this array to smarty...
$smarty->assign('$category', $cvalue);
```

**This Doesn't work:**

```
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_conx, "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM $storeShop");
     $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($category);

    /* fetch values */

    while ($line = ($stmt->fetch())) {
        $cvalue[] = $line;

    }

    // Assign this array to smarty...

    $smarty->assign('category', $cvalue);



  // Assign this array to smarty...
    $smarty->assign('$category', $cvalue);
```

am I missing anything in my prepared statement code? and what do I need to do to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: This works as well but it is not prepared statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM $storeShop";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the output amount
    while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $cvalue[] = $line;
    }
```

Comment: Btw, define "doesn't work"

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I mean it just doesn't return any value. It will create the empty spaces in my page as if its getting the values but it just simply doesn't print out the values.

Comment: well, now it's clearer. try to copy/paste prepared statment handling code from your source *without* mistakes.

Answer (score -3):

> is there any difference between select distinct in mysql function and mysqli prepared statement?

Obviously, no.
API syntax has absolutely nothing to do with SQL syntax.

Your problem is somewhere else. You need to learn to debug your application to make yourself aware of the *real* cause and eventually be able to post a question on the real problem you have, instead of blindly poking by chance. You may start here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/285587

Comment: Cheers, I have all that in my php file and I don't get any error(s).

Comment: Why post an answer if it (as you claim) is not answerable?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy it is answerable all right, and answered. If you can't see the answer, better quit that review business.

Comment: What the hell? You *literally* said "You need too learn to debug your application to make yourself aware of the real cause and eventually be able to post an answerable question on Stack Overflow", implying that the question is not answerable. Don't give me bullshit.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy that's *another* question, that was only *implied* by the OP. His real question is "Why doesn't my code work", while he preferred to ask a pointless one if there is any difference between two drivers. Again: if you can't read and comprehend the question - better quit that review business.